# Why does Ubuntu Software Center not show every package available?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-center, 16.04

The Software Center in Ubuntu 16.04 (Gnome Software) shows only part of the packages available. While e.g. `apt list qtcreator` correctly lists the corresponding package a search in Software Center finds nothing.

Is there something misconfigured? I upgraded from 15.10. Until now I have used the old Ubuntu Software Center which worked fine.

Comment: Ubuntu software center is not a package installer, but a software installer. It installs all packages which are necessary as a part of software. If you want package level control, install synaptic package manager.

Comment: @WeareBorg Ubuntu Software Center unfortunately does not show all available software. For example Ubuntu Software Center cannot find "keepass2". "apt list keepass2" does find it. It is not a package, but a "software". Another example is "arbtt". (Ubuntu 16.10)

Answer (score 3):

This issue persists even in 19.04:

The image below shows that I have installed *rofi* but the Software Center doesn't find it. It doesn't even show it in the "Installed" tab (not shown).

[image: Software Center doesn't find rofi]

Lubuntu, an official flavor, uses Openbox as its window manager. Again, the Software Center doesn't list it.

[image: Software Center doesn't find Openbox]

There are more examples.

In [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1051118/248158), there's a link to [a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1579415) from 2016 that could explain why some packages aren't listed. I'm copy/pasting some of what I think are points to note:

- From comment #2: gnome-software is meant to list graphical softwares only, technical items like samba are for more technical users and can be installed from the command line or synaptic
- From comment #7: the fact that some are not shown is a bug in the metadata generator or (more likely) the packaging or upstream software.
- From comment #9: the packages must match some criteria, and meeting those is the job of the individual package maintainers.
- From comment #12: Yeah, the old Ubuntu Software Center was designed to also replace Synaptic, while the new GNOME Software is for applications / fonts / other visible stuff only (the same as KDE Discover does).
  Advanced users are encouraged to use Synaptic, Muon or the command-line directly.

---

Comment #7 above referred to a metadata generator. If you're interested to know more, you'll could look at [Appstream](https://wiki.debian.org/AppStream) and [Help make Gnome Software beautiful](https://mhall119.com/blog/help-make-gnome-software-beautiful/). From the former link:

> AppStream is a cross-distro XML format to provide metadata for software components and to assign unique identifiers to software.

and

> The metadata can for example be used by software centers like GNOME Software or KDE Discover to display a user-friendly application-centric way on the package archive.

---

To my mind, then, there could be (at least) two reasons why packages aren't listed in software centers:

- metadata hasn't been generated at all for the package, possibly due to non-availability of human effort.
- issues with the metadata. See http://appstream.ubuntu.com/ for more.

The [Help make Gnome Software beautiful](https://mhall119.com/blog/help-make-gnome-software-beautiful/) blog post explains how you and I can help move things along.

Comment: In contrast to comment #2, my software center doesn't list [Golly](http://golly.sourceforge.net/) which is most definitely a graphical application.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. E.g. Can see openjfx in Ubuntu Software Center but not in new Ubuntu Software.
It seems you can still use Ubuntu Software Center which is still installed for me after upgrade from 14.04. For people who have clean installed 16.04, you can install Software Center by: `apt-get install software-center`

Ubuntu Software has been touted as replacement for Software Center so I think it should still show packages somehow.