# Missing Applications in Ubuntu software center

Tags: wine, software-center, playonlinux

I'm new so go easy as I know it may be a simple answer to most, however I came from Linux Mint and I know that the software center's are very similar.  I feel that mint is easier to use, however I know for gaming that ubuntu down right destroys the competition for linux distro's in fraps.  This is my reason for changing.  Also, for whatever reason(knock on wood) Ubuntu seems to run smoother than the Mint did(no idea why. I'm using the same partition as I did for Mint)

**What I want to know is why "Playonlinux" as well as "Wine" is missing from the Ubuntu software center after a fresh install.  Please, be specific when answering as I may follow up with another question if the answer is vague.  Thank you for your help.**

Comment: The following thread ( http://askubuntu.com/questions/773640/why-does-ubuntu-software-center-not-show-every-package-available/ ) is mentioning the same problem, without real solution

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt-get update` or something equivalent since the system installation?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem so I tried to reinstall the ubuntu software center. I don't know why but it works.

First of all, unlock it from launcher, click the right button on it and you see that option.
Then open the terminal and type

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

after that

`sudo apt-get install software-center`

If you use ubuntu 16.04 you could just type `apt` instead of `apt-get`.
And finally go to `/usr/share/applications`, find the new ubuntu software center and move it to the launcher.

Answer (score 0):

On my 14.04 wine and playonlinux are respectively in the "universe" and "multiverse" repositories. Check that you have these enabled in your software sources.

Comment: I have them as well via apt, but not via Software-Center. In other words: i can confirm the OPs problem on 16.04

Comment: On my 14.04 Softawre Center (KDE/Muon) I have PlayOnLinux but not Wine. But I find that the recent software centers somehow hide all the "utility" stuff. Locating a library through them is near impossible. So if you know the name of a package, better use *apt-get install*... I know, this may not really answer the question :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the new Ubuntu Software app isn't quite ideal. I can find neither Play on Linux nor Wine Windows Program Loader with it. However, If I install Ubuntu Software Center with `sudo apt-get install software-center`
and run Ubuntu Software Center instead of Ubuntu Software, both show up if I search wine.