# Why is Ubuntu Software Center dropping previously provided applications?

Tags: gnome-software

Ubuntu Software used to provide Pinta, KolourPaint, Audacity, and others, but they are no longer available there. I have to use apt to install them.

Why has Ubuntu Software 3.20.5 stopped providing applications that it used to?

Ubuntu 16.04
Ubuntu Software Center 3.20.5

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Here are a couple of bugs listed for this one:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1589970 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1579415

Comment: please put as answer and I'll mark it solution

Comment: Voting to close: Issues that turn out to be bug reports are off-topic here. Subscribe to bug reports at http://launchpad.net

Comment: Please see my update.  Might be something worth trying.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:**  Reading through one of the bug reports I was able to get mine back up and working with the following steps.  You might want to try it as well.  *This is only a temporary work around, as it doesn't last too long and you would probably have to run it again*.

Open a terminal window <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run the following lines:

```
pkill gnome-software
sudo rm -r /var/cache/app-info
sudo appstreamcli refresh --force --verbose
```

Then relaunch the `gnome-software` center.

---

Unfortunately this is a bug in the gnome-software application.  Here are a couple so far that I was able to find related to this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1589970

and

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-software/+bug/1579415

As an alternative you could use the Synaptic Package Manager.

```
sudo apt install synaptic
```

Or you could use the original Ubuntu Software Center that still works just not fully updated **(No longer available in 18.04)**:

```
sudo apt install software-center
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enable Ubuntu Repositories: Software and Updates - Enable Main and Universe. That should do it. Also I recommend you install flatpak plugin for the software center and you'll find more apps (and newer versions of them) https://itsfoss.com/flatpak-guide/

Software center 3.28.1 has Audacity, Pinta, KolourPaint and a ton of other apps :)

Comment: main and unverse are already selected. how do i install flatpak?

Comment: Follow the link I gave you. And if you don't see the above apps with Main and Universe then you should provide more details. Did you install Ubuntu and saw that such apps are missing? Did you upgrade? Did you install anything that could interfere with that?

Comment: As I said, main and universe already selected