# Installing ibus-m17n

Tags: ibus, malayalam

I want to install ibus-m17n for malayalam (Indian Regional language) in my system. I'd searched my ubuntu software system, but cant find ibus-m17n.  please help

Comment: You haven't said what release, https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ibus-m17n hows it's available.  Did you try a package manager (that lists everything such as `aptitude`, `synaptic` as some 'user' tools list stick to 'major' type titles)

Comment: fyi:  `sudo apt install ibus-m17n` would have installed it; prior comment was based at user-level tool rather than a command.

Answer (score 1):

You can install it via command

`sudo apt install ibus-m17n`

or load a package manager tool and search there, eg. `aptitude`, `synaptic`, `muon` etc.

[image]

Some software tools (eg. Ubuntu Software, Software Boutique, Discover) limit themselves to major or popular packages and don't list all packages to avoid 'clutter' or confusion.  Package managers are useful for less-common packages.

Comment: You could add *Discover* to the list of software centers that don't offer all packages.

Comment: See my excellent answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/773640/why-does-ubuntu-software-center-not-show-every-package-available/1145632#1145632)!

Comment: When writing my wording (*major or popular packages* or *best of the best*) I was thinking of *wimpy*'s introduction or justification for the *Software Boutique* (which included how the list used by *Software Boutique* was created) on what was probably the *Ubuntu Podcast*.   Yes yours was a great answer (+1)

Comment: Do you have a link to wimpy's post/blog or wherever that intro is? Thanks!

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think *wimpy* gave roughly the same in (*at least*) two podcasts; one of which maybe https://ubuntu-mate.org/blog/ubuntu-mate-and-ubuntu-software-center/ (destination linux ep103).  This isn't the one I was thinking of sorry (there was more focus on family in the one I was thinking of, and less phone-quality audio, this was possibly an earlier talk on topic)

Comment: maybe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gR8VnDZx_IU  @DKBose  (Destination Linux EP15 -- better than first I think)

Comment: I'm listening to https://www.jupiterbroadcasting.com/85672/oscon-secret-sauce-lup-103/ and wimpy appears about 8min into the podcast. So thanks!